# Upload a photo to Django in Swift 3 using Alamofire 4?

Tags: ios, django, swift, alamofire

I can't seem to upload a photo correctly to Django. Here's the problem.

`request.FILES` is empty. However, in the body I see a bunch of gibberish (which would be the photo data). I've tried this to make it work but it still shows as empty:

In Django:

```
class UploadPhoto(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.FILES)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In iOS:

```
    func photoUploader(photo: UIImage,  completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.8)

    guard let authToken = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: "userToken")?["token"] as? String else {
        return
    }

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": authToken]
    var url: URLRequest?

    do {
        url = try URLRequest(url: EntityURLs.uploadPhotoURL, method: .post, headers: headers)
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    if let url = url {
        upload(multipartFormData: { (mpd) in
            mpd.append(imageData!, withName: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }, with: url, encodingCompletion: { (success) in
            debugPrint(success)
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so to properly upload a file to Django using the Alamofire 4.0 framework, there was one thing I forgot to add: the file name.

In my case, I'm uploading "weeknd.jpg" so I have to change this:

```
 mpd.append(imageData!, withName: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

to this:

```
mpd.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "weeknd.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

In Django, the `request.FILES` now shows as such: `<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: weeknd.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>`

I pretty much forgot to add the fileName. Hopefully this will help someone.